# Understanding Drupal's session management and user authentication

Tags: 7, sessions, authentication-authorization

I have a requirement to replace the default user authentication with the authentication of a central server, i.e., the SSO server.
By debugging Drupal, I learned that all the session management happens in the `includes/session.inc` file. I want to do authentication as shown in the image:

[image: snap]

**SCENARIO: Login**
The details of the steps would be as follows:

1. Replace the login form to submit the username and password to the SSO server (**not on Drupal**, but on .NET).
2. Authenticate the user on the SSO server using that site's database, and send a response back to some custom PHP page of *my website* (or a form by a module?).
3. Using the response, identify the user in the *users* table, and create a session for that user without checking for the password (as it would mean double authentication).  By default, Drupal sets a cookie with the name of the `$insecure_session_name` variable and the value `$sid`. I want Drupal not to set the cookie here but instead send the values of variables to the SSO server.
4. The SSO server will take the values, create a cookie, and drop it in the domain `domain.com` (to remind both `my website` and `sso server` are on the subdomain of the main domain, which is not in Drupal). Then, the drupal site can log in by using that cookie.

I know it is a tough ask, but I am just looking for pointers on how to start. as they say, "you should not hack the core". So, my questions are:

1. Where should I look to understand how Drupal authentication and session management works in depth?
2. Is there a way I could call the functions in `includes/session.inc` using hooks (as the comments with functions say "for internal use only/not to be modified")?

**NOTE:** I'll be using the same method to register the user so that the record remains in the central database of the SSO server. And during that will put in some junk password for the same user in the Drupal site's database (as the password will not be checked during login).

Comment: Do you need true SSO (login to one site and you are logged into all sites), or just authenticating against an outside system?

Comment: @MPD I want a true SSO, which will require logging in in one site and --> authenticating same user on all sites (might not be on Drupal.

Comment: @AjitS if you have successfully implemented this can you please put detailed answer. i am using user_login_finalize but i am being told due to GDPR issues i cant store the details in Drupal.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Drupal supports *external authentication*. There are many alternatives authentication modules for Drupal, such as OpenID (included in core), [OAuth Connector](http://drupal.org/project/oauthconnector), or [LDAP](http://drupal.org/project/ldap). Learn more about how Drupal authentication works; the best would be to look at the OpenID and OAuth modules, and to the core login form submit callback. But, AFAIK, they always start the normal Drupal session after a successful authentication.

For session management, Drupal plugs into PHP session handling and register it own handlers. The Drupal session backend is itself pluggable, you can set the `session_inc` variable to the path of a file providing alternative implementations of the functions found in `includes/session.inc`. The [memcache](http://drupal.org/project/memcache) module use this to store session in memcached.

For references, the OpenID module handle successful authentication in `openid_authentication()` which itself *ceats* and call the user login form submit handler (ie. `user_login_submit()`). This submit handler itself is simple, it loads the successfully authenticated user with `user_load()` into the global `$user` variable, it then call `user_login_finalize()` which handle session, login timestamp in the `user` table and invoke `hook_user_login()` implementations.

Another option is the use the [`user_external_login_register()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_external_login_register/7) function. The function will log an external user in. It also creates a local user if needed. If you need more control on local user creation, you can always use [`user_save()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_save/7), [`user_set_authmaps()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_set_authmaps/7),  [`user_login_submit()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_login_submit/7) and [`user_external_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_external_load/7) from you custom call, using `user_external_login_register()` as template of what needs to be done.

Comment: This is pretty much spot on.  The Drupal side of logging in external users is suprisingly easy.  The heavy lifting (if any) is actually interfacing with the external system.

Comment: @mpdonadio Finding the opposite, in my particular case. External system = JSON web service = relatively easy stuff. Drupal behaviour = unpredictably changing from version to version = difficult as hell and no useful diagnostics when things break.

Answer (score 1):

[user_authenticate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_authenticate/7) APi might come in handy here.

> 3.Using the response, identify the user in the *users* table, and create a session for that user without checking for the password (as
>   it would mean double authentication).  By default, Drupal sets a
>   cookie with name of `$insecure_session_name` variable, and with value
>   `$sid`. I want Drupal not to set the cookie here, instead send the
>   values of variables to SSO server.

EDIT : Once SSO server returns with true use this API to login the user which will automatically take care of sessions for you.
I think its better if you use `user_authenticate()` instead of creating sessions by yourself. It shouldnt make a problem even its a double authentication as long as valid p-assowrd is provided.

Am not sure of 4. Do you want the cookie to be visible in both domains ? If so then in settings.php initialize  `$cookie_domain` to the domain. Then cookies in subsite will be available in parent site.

Comment: thank you for your response. I can't use `user_authenticate` because, the authentication doesn't need to happen on Drupal site. I can generate the session by calling `drupal_session_generate()` and `drupal_session_regenerate()` from session.inc file.
You got it right about requirement for cookie..
please see the edit.

Comment: @indrock Check that link. User_authenticate will allow you to login a user provided username & password are correct. In Step 3 when you verify that username & pass is correct on SSO server then use this API to login the user. But you should have password stored on Drupal. Doing this will make it much easier than hacking core.