# Add users from SSO server database to Drupal

Tags: 7, hooks, authentication-authorization

I am trying to implement an SSO system for Drupal system. The detailed description of the scenario can be seen in "[Understanding Drupal's session management and user authentication](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39065/understanding-drupals-session-management-and-user-authentication)".

I did implement the authentication part, as per the using the suggestions provided (thanks to Pierre Buyle). Now, I have a requirement to add the users to Drupal database which are already present in SSO database.
The IT team of SSO will create a form which will post this values to a URL on the Drupal site.

This URL have to catch the request and create a user in Drupal. I'll be using the method [`user_save()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_save/7) to achieve this.

My questions are:

1. How do I create this URL in Drupal? (Thought of using `hook_menu` and use `$items` to create the URL, but I don't want it to be accessible to users except admin.
2. How could I read the data from that URL?

I'm not asking for the complete code. Just pointers to which *hooks* or *methods* should I use for the use cases would be enough.

Comment: Wheres the form ? In drupal site ? Then why dont you use a normal register form ? It saves you coding trouble , since you mentioned they will do data entry manually.

Comment: @kantu the form is on SSO server (implemented in ASP). So, the IT team will submit the values to Drupal via a form POST, which I need to use to create the user in Drupal.

Comment: The functions you want to look at are in the approved comment you linked. Dont use `user_save()` look at what `openid_authenticate()` does or `user_external_login_register()` does. You can read the Post params via $_POST ...

Comment: @tenken any specific reason not for directly using `user_save()`?

Comment: If you look at like user_external_login_authenticate() or I think user_authenticate() they eventually call a user_save(). Eventually you will want to call user_save() but there is alot of other little things you will likely want/need todo as well in your authentication script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, integration of different system through form POSting is at the hack level. To let external system inject data into Drupal, the [Services](http://drupal.org/project/services) module let you easily build HTTP REST API in Drupal. It comes out of the box with a user API that allow external system to easily create new Drupal users.

Off course, you can create your own *page* to receive POSTed data from a form build outside Drupal. You simply have to declare it through a `hook_menu()` implementation. For access control to the page, you can either use the `'access arguments'` to restrict access with Drupal permission system. you can also use your own `'access callback'` to implement your own access control logic (ie. for instance, using a secret token based access control).

Answer (score 1):

Used [`hook_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) to create an URL, and got the values which were POSTed on this URL (as per @Pierre 's suggestion)

```
function MYMODULE_menu() {
    $items['add-new-user'] = array (
        'title' => '',
        'type' => 'MENU_CALLBACK',
        'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_add_new_custom_user',
        'page arguments' => array($_POST),
        'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'), //Admin access only
    );
    return $items;
}
```

In the function to create user, used [`user_save()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_save/7) to save the user.

```
function MYMODULE_add_new_custom_user($post_value) {
    $account = new stdClass();
    $account->is_new = TRUE; //This is a new account
    $edit = array (     
        'roles' => array(
          //left empty because only needed to create authenticated users
        ),
        'administer_users' => FALSE,
        'name' => $post_values['username'],
        'mail' => $post_values['mail'],
        'status' => FALSE,   //newly created user would have STATUS as blocked.
        'notify' => 0,
        'timezone' => 'America/Chicago',
        'signature' => '',
        'picture' => '',
        'picture_delete' => '',
        'picture_upload' => '',
        'signature_format' => 'filtered_html',
        'pass' => $post_values['pass'],
        'init' => $post_values['mail'],     
    );

    $user_obj = user_save($account, $edit, 'account');
    if(isset($user_obj->uid)) { //as $user_obj will be an object of stdClass and not an array.
      //user created
    }
    else {
      //some error occurred, handled seperately;
      //user_save returns FALSE if saving a users returns any error. 
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised `'page arguments' => array($_POST),` works. Page arguments in `hook_menu` are resolved when the menu cahe is rebuild, not when the age is accessed.

Comment: @PierreBuyle Not sure. This was one of my initial tasks when I started working with Drupal, and I remember this to be working! Now I realize what a loophole I ended up creating that time without a CSRF token ;)